# I just saw that certain commits I made had the author <unix-username>.localdomain. What do I do?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows subsystem for linux, with ubuntu distro. 
I generally access git commands from the bash. I was making commits the other day and I saw that their author was not my git hub account but `wolfbaseplate@DESKTOP-08P153Q.localdomain`  where `wolfbaseplate@DESKTOP-08P153Q` is the name of my UNIX account on ubuntu. 
Is there a way I could fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+commit+name

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your account using following commands

```
git config --global user.name 'Your Name'

git config --global user.email 'you@domain.com'
```